Chrome extention - Calling a content function from a non content js file
I am trying to build a chrome extension and I am having a hard time trying to call a function that is inside "content.js" from another regular js file.
the purpose function inside content.js is to fill all the input tags inside the DOM of the tab I am currently on to a given value that I choose inside my extension page.
manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "icons": {
    "48": "assets/icon48.png",
    "128": "assets/icon128.png"
  },
  "action":{
      "default_popup": "extension.html",
      "default_title": ""
  },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["js/content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "scripting"
    ]
}

js/content.js:
function changeInput(value) {
    if (event.target.id == "input-btn") {
        const passwordInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='password']");
        passwordInputs.forEach(input => {
            input.value = value;
        });
    }
}

extension.html:
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-page.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login-page.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="input-btn">change input value</button>
        <script src="js/request_password.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

js/request_password.js:
document.addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
    if (event.target.id == "input-btn") {
        changeInput("Hello world");
    } 
});

I know that you can't just call another function from a different file without exporting it but even with import/export, the call won't work.
I am not sure but I think that I can't call a content function from a non content script.
How can I call the content function?
Thanks for the help!

Remove content_scripts from manifest.json and use chrome.scripting.executeScript, more info.
